# Why is my Bitnami WordPress website deployed on AWS (free tier) not accessible?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, themes, bitnami

The website domain is www.myhomeetal.com. I tried to view the logs via SSH on the server, this is what I got.

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/revo/lib/widgets.php on line 714\n'
```

and this

```
 Certificate and private key localhost:443:0 from /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt and /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key do not match
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

I attempted installing an SSL certificate when I noticed the site was offline. Could that have caused the whole site to be offline.

Comment: Side-note: AWS does not offer a 'free account'. The [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) does provide a certain amount of services at no charge during the first 12 months, but any usage beyond these amounts will be charged.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The PHP warning probably isn't relevant - that would not prevent the site from starting up. However, an SSL cert problem probably would. The error is "Certificate and private key do not match". Do you have copies of this you can re-send to the server?

Comment: @halfer ..noted sir.

Comment: l have reverted the ssl install process by deleting the csr and private key from the application root. l restarted apache and it ran normally. but l can only access the application from the domain assigned by aws. the domain myhomeetal.com previously mapped to the website does not access the website..a dns lookup of the domain shows no dns entry.. Please why is this

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bitnami Engineer here,

It seems that Apache is running properly now but the DNS is not properly configured. As you can see in this online tool, the ec2 and www.myhomeetal.com are set properly to the machine's IP but the myhomeetal.com domain is not

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/ec2-18-191-15-113.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.myhomeetal.com
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/myhomeetal.com

You just need to configure myhomeetal.com to point to the machine's IP

Happy to help!